# Get user location using flutter

Tags: flutter, geolocation

I'm using the geolocator plugin to access the user's location but it seems like it does not work, cause when I run my code I get the error on message.

I have done all the geolocation configuration, but I have the problem.

Adding the Geolocator plugin(pubspec.yaml)

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  geolocator: ^5.1.3
```

For android, head on over to your AndroidManifest.xml and add either of these permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

Source code for getting address

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  final Geolocator geolocator = Geolocator()..forceAndroidLocationManager;
  Position _currentPosition;
  String _currentAddress;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Location"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            if (_currentPosition != null) Text(_currentAddress),
            FlatButton(
              child: Text("Get location"),
              onPressed: () {
                _getCurrentLocation();
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  _getCurrentLocation() {
    geolocator
        .getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.best)
        .then((Position position) {
      setState(() {
        _currentPosition = position;
      });
      _getAddressFromLatLng();
    }).catchError((e) {
      print(e);
    });
  }

  _getAddressFromLatLng() async {
    try {
      List<Placemark> p = await geolocator.placemarkFromCoordinates(
          _currentPosition.latitude, _currentPosition.longitude);
      Placemark place = p[0];
      setState(() {
        _currentAddress =
            "${place.locality}, ${place.postalCode}, ${place.country}";
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
}
```

The problem I get when I run my code is here.

[image: My error massage]

Answer (score 0):

Try `flutter clean` on terminal and then run the app again, You can also use [location](https://pub.dev/packages/location) plugin instead of Geolocator, to get the user's location

Comment: do you have please any example for location plugin to get the user address

Comment: Hope this helps @MrFlutter : https://pub.dev/packages/location/example